# sax parsing: take value from div tag

Tags: android, xml-parsing, sax

I am doing an Android application.  In my app I have to parse a xml page.The data in the xml page is in the following format.

```
<root>
<tag1>data</tag1>

<tag2> 
<div>data1</div><div>data2</div>
</tag2>
</root>
```

to tried to take data through sax parsing.

```
 if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("tag1"))
if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("tag2"))
```

But I am not getting any data from tag2 but getting value from tag1.I want to get all data include div tag also then only i can show data in like html page.

Comment: you have to also use the if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("div"))

Comment: i want that div tag too....then only i can show the the content in the html format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this sample code

```
public class SAXParserDemo extends DefaultHandler {

    private String currentTag = "";
    private StringBuffer responseTag;
    private String str;

    @Override
    public void startDocument() throws SAXException {
        super.startDocument();

    }

    @Override
    public void endDocument() throws SAXException {
        super.endDocument();
    }

    @Override
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String name,
            Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
        super.startElement(uri, localName, name, attributes);

        currentTag = localName;
        if ("tag1".equalsIgnoreCase(localName)) {
            responseTag = new StringBuffer();
        }else if ("tag2".equalsIgnoreCase(localName)) {
            responseTag = new StringBuffer();
        }else if ("div".equalsIgnoreCase(localName)) {
            responseTag = new StringBuffer();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String name)
            throws SAXException {
        super.endElement(uri, localName, name);
        String responseValue = responseTag.toString().trim();

        if ("tag1".equalsIgnoreCase(localName)) {
            Log.v("TAG", "Tag 1 value "+responseValue);
        }else if ("tag2".equalsIgnoreCase(localName)) {
            Log.v("TAG", "Tag 2 value "+responseValue);
        }else if ("div".equalsIgnoreCase(localName)) {
            Log.v("TAG", "div value "+responseValue);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
            throws SAXException {
        super.characters(ch, start, length);
        str = new String(ch, start, length);

        if ("tag1".equalsIgnoreCase(currentTag)) {
            responseTag.append(str);
        }else if ("tag2".equalsIgnoreCase(currentTag)) {
            responseTag.append(str);
        }else if ("div".equalsIgnoreCase(currentTag)) {
            responseTag.append(str);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you can see the div value in logcat. If u still have problem then please share your code.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SAX parsing, you need to look for the `div` element and you need to keep track of the parent element (yourself) and make sure that's `tag2`. You are getting the data (characters) in the `tag1` element because it directly contains those characters. The `tag2` element does not contain any (non-whitespace) characters, only other elements.